# How to round the sum of decimal numbers more accurately in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a way to round the sum of an array of numbers in more accurate way.
for example giving an array of `[33.33, 33.33, 33.33]` the sum is 99.99 in this case I don't want to round the sum to be 100.
but if the array of numbers was `[33.3333 , 33.3333, 33.3333]` then it should round the sum to 100.
Using `Math.round()` is rounding always to 100 even if you have an array of [33.22 , 33.33 , 33.33]

Comment: Why shouldn't the first one round to 100 and the second one should?

Comment: what result do you expect?

Comment: You have to user round and floor methods based in a tipping point, which you have to decide.  Math.floor(99.999)
99
Math.round(99.999)
100
Math.floor(99.6)

Comment: These are standard results.  For rounding (generally) you take .5 and above and round up, and <.5 rounds down.  Tell us what you actually want if you want us to help you do it.

Comment: Math.round will round up when the decimals are >=0.5.   0.33+0.33+0.22 > 0.5 so it will round up

Answer (score 3):

You could multiply before rounding to have different precision:

```js
var a = 99.99;
var b = 99.9999;
var precision = 100;

console.log(a, Math.round(a), Math.round(a * precision) / precision);
console.log(b, Math.round(b), Math.round(b * precision) / precision);
```

Answer (score 3):

The better solution to round off a number is demoed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

```js
function precisionRound(number, precision) {
  var factor = Math.pow(10, precision);
  return Math.round(number * factor) / factor;
}

console.log(precisionRound(99.99, 2)); //99.99
console.log(precisionRound(99.9999, 2)); //100
```